# Unable to start an Activity from Application class - Android

Tags: android

I am trying to access if user is logged in or not, based on that I try to start activity for the application. While doing this, the app crashes in the Application class.

**The code for application class is**

```
public class MyClass extends Application {
    public static Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();

        if(ParseUser.getCurrentUser().isAuthenticated()){
            startActivity(new Intent(context, MainActivity.class));
        }

    }
}
```

Any suggestion why this happens ?

In my Manifest I have declared the intent filter for another activity.

```
 <activity
            android:name=".Activities.Register"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_register" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: did you add flag to Intent? ````intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);````

Comment: I dont think so. Where and how to add it ?

Comment: you declared Register in AndroidManifest but you use MainActivity.class for startActivity?!

Comment: Yes, I just want to check if user is present, then go to MainActivity else go to register, so which one do you think, I can declare in Manifest ?

Comment: all the activities should be declared in manifest before you can even start them....Android 101?

Comment: Dude, I have declared main activity in Manifest, but that is not kept as the laucher activity, my question is which one can I keep as launcher activity ?

Comment: then the Register is not related to this question as the only concern here is MainActivity

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Also if you look at Logcat in Android Studio, you should be seeing error log that has already told you how to fix this issue.

Comment: sorry, the log is not working properly. Sometimes, it does not print anything.

Comment: that's fine, does it help?

Comment: Ya it helps, I upvoted. Yet to accept as I got 6 min to accept. LOL. Pls suggest me with the manifest question ?

Answer (score 2):

You are not supposed to start new activity in application class. IMO it will be much better if remove totally activity starting code in application class and having same activity on start just choose a fragment to attach depending on user is logged in or not.